# Can we convert an array output from JSON as URL

Tags: html, json, ajax

I am currently working on ajax and I am very new to it. What I am trying to achieve is to convert an array that I am fetching from the database, I would like to display as clickable link instead of pain text.
My AJAX code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#target li').click(function()
    {

       $.getJSON("getMakes.php?name="+$(this).text(), success = function(data)

       {
        var item = "";
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      {
        item +=  "<li id='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i]+ "</li>";


      }
      $("#slctModel").html("");
      $("#slctModel").append(item);
            });

        });
    });
```

HTML bit where I am getting the output somewhat looks like this:

```
                <div id="slctCat">
                <ul class="b">
                    <li id ="slctModel"></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

final output in the form of plain text:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

I wd like an user to be able click on these items as links...
Please help.

Comment: So – output `a` elements with the appropriate(?) `href` attribute set within your list items …

Answer (score 1):

Put an `a` tag inside each `li` with your link.

`item += "<li id='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'><a href = 'your-link'>" + data[i]+ "</a></li> ";`

Also you should `append` to the `ul` and not `li`. So do `$(".b").empty().append(item);`